# Error : appbridgeError: APP::ERROR::INVALID_CONFIG: shopOrigin must be provided

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, shopify

I made the Shopify App with Koa, Nextjs tho, I got this error

`appbridgeError: APP::ERROR::INVALID_CONFIG: shopOrigin must be provided`

App behavior is a little strange because when I access the first time, it goes well.
However, a few hours later, I get this error. And then I researched the problem tho, I found the case. `Cookies.get("shopOrigin")` in MyApp class is going to be empty after a few hours later.

**[server.js's part of code]**

```
....................
....................

app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  var httpServer = http.createServer(serverCallback);
  // var httpsServer = https.createServer(config.https.options, serverCallback);

  server.use(session({ secure: true, sameSite: 'none' }, server));
  server.keys = [SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY];
  server.use(
    createShopifyAuth({
      apiKey: SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
      secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
      scopes: [
        'read_products','write_products',
        'read_orders', 'write_orders',
        'read_customers', 'write_customers',
        'read_script_tags', 'write_script_tags'
      ],
      afterAuth(ctx) {
        const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;

        ACCESS_TOKEN = accessToken

        ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, {
          httpOnly: false,
          secure: true,
          sameSite: 'none',
        });
        ctx.redirect('/');
      },
    }),
  );

  server.use(graphQLProxy({version: ApiVersion.October19}))
  server.use(verifyRequest());
  server.use(async (ctx) => {
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
    ctx.respond = false;
    ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
    return
  });
....................
....................
```

**[_app.js]**

```
....................
....................

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    const config = { apiKey: API_KEY, shopOrigin: Cookies.get("shopOrigin"), forceRedirect: true };
    console.log(`config`)
    console.log(config)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Head>
          <title>My LA Meats</title>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        </Head>
       <Provider config={config}>
          <AppProvider i18n={translations}>
            <ApolloProvider client={client}>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ApolloProvider>
          </AppProvider>
        </Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
....................
....................
```

I guess this is cookie's problem tho, I can't confirm it. Do you guys have the same problems? If you know how I should resolve this problem, let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same error after changing 0 lines of code, it seems to arise because the `shopOrigin` cookie is HttpOnly. To confirm this I'd try running something like `document.cookie` in the console and see if the shopOrigin cookie shows up.

In my case the cookie was visible in chrome and firefox, and once I unticked the HttpOnly column for the shopOrigin cookie I was able to load my app. However, this is a temporary fix because the cookie is reset to HttpOnly on a restart of chrome. This is puzzling because the `createShopifyAuth()` function in server.js explicitly creates the cookie so that it is not HttpOnly.

Please let me know if you find a solution.